Complete Mantra or part of Sloka
Is the below mantra, complete mantra or part of sloka.
ॐ नमो भगवते वासुदेवाय धन्वन्तरये अमृतकलश हस्ताय |
सर्वामय विनाशनाय त्रैलोक्यनाथाय श्री महाविष्णवे नमः ||

This sloka is part of the complete Dhanvantari Mantra given here.
धन्वंतरी मंत्र
ध्यानं
अच्युतानंत गोविंद विष्णो नारायणाऽमृत
रोगान्मे नाशयाऽशेषानाशु धन्वंतरे हरे ।
आरोग्यं दीर्घमायुष्यं बलं तेजो धियं श्रियं
स्वभक्तेभ्योऽनुगृह्णंतं वंदे धन्वंतरिं हरिम् ॥
शंखं चक्रं जलौकां दधदमृतघटं चारुदोर्भिश्चतुर्भिः ।
सूक्ष्मस्वच्छातिहृद्यांशुक परिविलसन्मौलिमंभोजनेत्रम् ।
कालांभोदोज्ज्वलांगं कटितटविलसच्चारुपीतांबराढ्यम् ।
वंदे धन्वंतरिं तं निखिलगदवनप्रौढदावाग्निलीलम् ॥
धन्वंतरेरिमं श्लोकं भक्त्या नित्यं पठंति ये ।
अनारोग्यं न तेषां स्यात् सुखं जीवंति ते चिरम् ॥
मंत्रं
ॐ नमो भगवते वासुदेवाय धन्वंतरये अमृतकलशहस्ताय [वज्रजलौकहस्ताय] सर्वामयविनाशनाय त्रैलोक्यनाथाय श्रीमहाविष्णवे स्वाहा ।
[पाठांतरः]
ॐ नमो भगवते महासुदर्शनाय वासुदेवाय धन्वंतरये अमृतकलशहस्ताय सर्वभयविनाशाय सर्वरोगनिवारणाय त्रैलोक्यपतये त्रैलोक्यनिधये श्रीमहाविष्णुस्वरूप श्रीधन्वंतरीस्वरूप श्री श्री श्री औषधचक्र नारायणाय स्वाहा ।
गायत्री मंत्रम्
ॐ वासुदेवाय विद्महे सुधाहस्ताय धीमहि ।
तन्नो धन्वंतरिः प्रचोदयात् ।
तारकमंत्रम्
ॐ धं धन्वंतरये नमः ।
A variation of this mantra, with minor differences, can also be found here.

ॐ नमो भगवते महासुदर्शनाय वासुदेवाय धन्वंतराये:
अमृतकलश हस्ताय सर्व भयविनाशाय सर्व रोगनिवारणाय
त्रिलोकपथाय त्रिलोकनाथाय श्री महाविष्णुस्वरूप
श्री धनवंतरी स्वरूप श्री श्री श्री औषधचक्र नारायणाय नमः॥
